# Write "for loop" results in a txt file

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

the script runs fine, but only records the last result in the .txt file. What am i doing wrong?

```
a= float(input('Insert a: '))
b= float(input('Insert b: '))

for c in range(10,300):
    d= float(46+(9*a)-(7*c))
    e= float(-6+(463*b)+(-1*c)+(0.8*a)+(0.89*d))
    print(d)
    print(e)


import sys
sys.stdout=open("loop.txt","w")
print(d)
print(e)
sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: Maybe you should open the file BEFORE the loop.

Comment: this is because you will write after your loop, so `d` and `e` have the last computed values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write these values inside the loop itself

```
a= float(input('Insert a: '))
b= float(input('Insert b: '))

with open("loop.txt","w") as f_out:
    for c in range(10,300):
        d= float(46+(9*a)-(7*c))
        e= float(-6+(463*b)+(-1*c)+(0.8*a)+(0.89*d))
        f_out.write('{} {}\n'.format(d, e))
```

Comment: works wonderful, can you send me a link with options to format the output?

Comment: [This page](https://pyformat.info/) is a good reference for string formatting, including precision, padding, sig figs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the stream before doing anything :

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open("loop.txt", "w")

a= float(input('Insert a: '))
b= float(input('Insert b: '))

for c in range(10,300):
    d= float(46+(9*a)-(7*c))
    e= float(-6+(463*b)+(-1*c)+(0.8*a)+(0.89*d))
    print(d)
    print(e)

sys.stdout.close()
```